# How do I retrieve only one specific file from a 7z instead of unzipping and dumping to a folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, archive, 7zip

Currently, I am using `7ZipCLI` to unzip my `.7z` folder to a specified folder `destPath` like this:

```
private void ExtractFile(string archivePath, string destPath)
{
    string zpath = @"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\x64\7za.exe";
    try
    {
        ProcessStartInfo pro = new ProcessStartInfo();
        pro.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        pro.FileName = zpath;
        pro.Arguments = string.Format("x \"{0}\" -y -o\"{1}\"", archivePath, destPath);
        Process x = Process.Start(pro);
        x.WaitForExit();
    }
    catch (System.Exception Ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception: ", Ex)
    }
}
```

This takes a long time because the application unzips the folder, unloads it into `destPath` then does a search within destPath for the specified file. How would I instead look into the `.7z`, find the specified file and copy just that file to destPath?

Comment: i do wonder if these [command line](https://superuser.com/a/683817/534347) works.

Comment: I have tried using the -r command as suggested. As this is just a non-production application, the man page pointed out in the answer states specifically not to use it. I used it anyway just to see what would happen. It does not generate any file and errors out because the file it is looking for can not be found later on in the workflow of this application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do interesting things with archives I would suggest that you use a library instead of rolling your own process execution solution.  There are NuGet packages for just about every task, and this is no exception.

For instance, [SharpCompress](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sharpcompress/) is a fairly common library that handles decompressing 7z archives well enough for most uses.  Add that to your project and try something like this:

```
// Usings:
//  SharpCompress.Archives;
//  SharpCompress.Common;
//  System.Linq;

private static bool ExtractFile(string archivePath, string destPath, string fileSubstring)
{
    using (var archive = ArchiveFactory.Open(archivePath))
    {
        var entry = archive.Entries.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Key.Contains(fileSubstring));
        if (entry != null)
        {
            var opt = new ExtractionOptions
            {
                ExtractFullPath = false,
                Overwrite = true
            };
            try
            {
                entry.WriteToDirectory(destPath, opt);
                return true;
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

That's a simple example.  You could pass in a filter predicate and process multiple results, whatever fits your requirements.

Running a few tests here using SysInternals ProcMon to confirm, this does not create extraneous files and works quickly pulling little files out of big archives.

And as a bonus it doesn't care what type of archive you give it, as long as it's one that's supported by the library.  It'll read RAR, ZIP, 7z and a host of others, and you can use the same library to do compression for a few common formats if needed.